# How does this double recursion function work?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand this/visualize it in any way possible to no avail.

```
def f(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]

print f("mat")
print f("math")
```

Output:

```
atm
hatm
```

Comment: [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+f(s)%3A%0A++++if+len(s)+%3C%3D+1%3A%0A++++++++return+s%0A++++return+f(f(s%5B1%3A%5D))+%2B+s%5B0%5D%0A%0Aprint+f(%22mat%22)%0Aprint+f(%22math%22)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0)

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only did you help me figure this out, but that tool is priceless and will probably become a daily tool of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving you the answer, I will suggest a method. Whenever you are unsure what your code is doing, insert lots of `print` statements to see what is happening at each step. For example,

```
def f(s):
    print 'running f...'
    print 'input is',s
    if len(s) <= 1:
        print 's is <= 1'
        return s
    return f(f(s[1:])) + s[0]
```

The print statement is one of your best tools when you are debugging.